# How to efficiently add and remove classes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

i have managed to get this code working, but it doesnt make sense to me, its too long, there must be another way to do this or simplify it. can some one point me in the right direction ?

thanks

```
var TabbedContent = {
init: function() {      

$(".menu > li").click(function(e){
    switch(e.target.id){
        case "htab1":
            //change status & style menu
            $("#htab1").addClass("active");
            $("#htab2").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab3").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab4").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab5").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab6").removeClass("active");
            //display selected division, hide others
            $("div.htab1").fadeIn();
            $("div.htab2").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab3").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab4").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab5").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab6").css("display", "none");
        break;
        case "htab2":
            //change status & style menu
            $("#htab1").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab2").addClass("active");
            $("#htab3").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab4").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab5").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab6").removeClass("active");          
            //display selected division, hide others
            $("div.htab2").fadeIn();
            $("div.htab1").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab3").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab4").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab5").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab6").css("display", "none");
        break;
        case "htab3":
            //change status & style menu
            $("#htab1").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab2").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab3").addClass("active");
            $("#htab4").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab5").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab6").removeClass("active");  
            //display selected division, hide others
            $("div.htab3").fadeIn();
            $("div.htab1").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab2").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab4").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab5").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab6").css("display", "none");
        break;
        case "htab4":
            //change status & style menu
            $("#htab1").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab2").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab3").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab4").addClass("active");
            $("#htab5").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab6").removeClass("active");          
            //display selected division, hide others
            $("div.htab4").fadeIn();
            $("div.htab1").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab2").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab3").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab5").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab6").css("display", "none");
        break;case "htab5":
            //change status & style menu
            $("#htab1").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab2").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab3").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab4").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab5").addClass("active");
            $("#htab6").removeClass("active");      
            //display selected division, hide others
            $("div.htab5").fadeIn();
            $("div.htab1").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab2").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab3").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab4").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab6").css("display", "none");
        break;case "htab6":
            //change status & style menu
            $("#htab1").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab2").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab3").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab4").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab5").removeClass("active");
            $("#htab6").addClass("active");
            //display selected division, hide others
            $("div.htab6").fadeIn();
            $("div.htab1").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab2").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab3").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab4").css("display", "none");
            $("div.htab5").css("display", "none");
        break;
    }
    //alert(e.target.id);
    return false
});
}};
```

Comment: Please also show your markup. For now I can only say: it is certainly possible to make this nicer :).

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".menu > li").click(function(e){
    $(".menu > li").removeClass('active'); // assuming li elements go 'active'
    $(".menu > li > div").hide();
    $("#" + e.target.id).addClass('active');
    $("div." + e.target.id).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: His divs have different classes, not IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making this `id` based, you should add a `class` to each of your elements to make your JQuery shorter. Thus:

```
// ...
switch(e.target.id){
    case "htab1":
        //change status & style menu
        $(".menuItem").removeClass("active");
        $("#htab1").addClass("active");
// ...
```

Comment: Searching by class is one of the slowest things you can do in JavaScript. He's better off finding the container of tab items and setting the child objects (i.e. the individual tab items) class from there.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "categorization" CSS class for your tabs so that you can change them all at once.  For example:

```
$(".menu > li").click(function(e){
    var activeTab = "#" + e.target.id;
    var activeDiv = "." + e.target.id;
    $(".htabs").removeClass("active");
    $(".htabDivs").css("display", "none");
    $(activeTab).addClass("active");
    $(activeDiv).fadeIn();
    return false
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure your content DIV tabs have separate IDs, not separate classes (e.g. `#htab1`) and *one* class in common (e.g. `.htab`).  Likewise your menu elements (e.g. `#hmenu1` and `.hmenu`)

Given we don't know anything about your markup and element hierarchy, then try this:

```
$(".menu > li").click(function(e) {
     // "this" is the clicked element in jQuery handlers
     $('.hmenu').not(this).removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');

     // make a selector for the relevant tab
     var tab = this.id.replace('hmenu', '#htab');
     $('.htab').not(tab).css('display', 'none');
     $(tab).fadeIn();
});
```

More efficient code is possible if, for example, your tabs and menu items are all grouped under their own respective parents.  With such markup you can use `.siblings()` instead of class-based selectors to find all other elements in that group:

```
$(".menu > li").click(function(e) {
     // "this" is the clicked element in jQuery handlers
     $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

     // make a selector for the relevant tab
     var tab = this.id.replace('hmenu', '#htab');
     $(tab).fadeIn().siblings().css('display', 'none');
});
```